# Display Project records on click of input filed

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-lightning

I am new to aura components . I have field where project records are to be displayed .[On click of field I should get project records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0E96.jpg)
Desired output[On click of input field , I should get records like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JUWS.jpg) 
Can anyone help me

```
    **Component :** 


    <aura:component >
          <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
       <lightning:layoutItem size="4">
         <table> <tr><td style="padding:20px;">
             <lightning:input type="sObject" aura:id="test" name="Project" label="Project" value="" placeholder="search project" onClick="{!c.handleClick}"/>
             </td></tr>
             </table>
             </lightning:layoutItem>
            </div> 
    </aura:component>
    
    **Controller :**
    public class ListOfProjects {
        @AuraEnabled
        public  static List<project__c> getProjectList() {
            List<project__c> myProjects = [SELECT Name from project__c ];
            return myProjects;
        }
    }
    
    **.Js file :** 
    ({
        handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
            var action = component.get("c.getProjectList");
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
               console.log(response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.Projects" ,response.getReturnValue());
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
    })


[Required output][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQhXw.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lightning:combobox

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:combobox/example